# Java displaying score with image digits

Tags: image, integer

Is there any shortcut to display score as digits? I have digits from 0 to 9. So if score is 189 it should draw 189 so it is image 1, 8 and 9. If i had to do if statement for every possible outcome it is not worth it.
I tried it with:

```
if(a ==1 && a<2)
g.drawImage(image1,0,0,this);
```

So is there any way i can split integer to digits and call g.drawImage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1. Create 10 images, one for each digit and use an array to refer to each picture, e.g.

```
Image[] D = new Image[] {
    new Image("0.png"),
    new Image("1.png"),
    new Image("2.png"),
    new Image("3.png"),
    new Image("4.png"),
    new Image("5.png"),
    new Image("6.png"),
    new Image("7.png"),
    new Image("8.png"),
    new Image("9.png"),
}
```

Step 2: Convert your number to string:

```
String digits = number + "";
```

For each digit in `digits` draw the corresponding picture.

```
for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++)
    drawImage(x, y, D[digits.charAt(i) - '0']);
```

You have to adjust the values of `x` and `y` according to the size of your pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Ever think of doing mod? Meaning `score % 10` gives you the first (far right) digit, then `score /= 10`. Rinse and repeat. Maybe use a temp if you don't want to modify the score directly. Keep track of how many mods you do and the width of the images and you can produce the image.

eg.

```
int widthOfImgs;//put ur val here, if constant width
//otherwise you'll need to add the width of the images 
// and replace the (widthOfImgs * countMod) with curOffset
//int curOffset = 0;
int countMod = 0, temp = score;//assuming its an integer score
while (temp > 0){//given the score is always positive
    switch(temp % 10){
        case 1:
                //draw 1
                g.drawImage(image1,farRightPos - widthOfImgs * countMod,0,this);
                //curOffset += widthOfImage1;
                //dont recall the exact syntax daImage.width?
        case 2:
        //blah blah
    }
    ++countMod;// if the images are of constant width
    temp /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Looking that just now. And i think it might work. I'm thinking something like this. If i have max score like 6 digits i will place 6 zeros for start. And check score. If score is updated i can have 6 temp variables that might get value, and i can run them through if statement, and repaint images.

Comment: I believe this should work as long as the score is a positive integer.  And that the img widths are constant, but you can adjust it accordingly (I'll add that in).

Comment: Yes score is an integer value.